# Why it always returns 'foo'?

Tags: javascript

I've decided to create a small app that gives you randomly 2 numbers and a sign (- or +) if the user answers correctly it should `console.log('hey');` and show new 2 numbers and a sign. Now my app only shows two numbers and always says `console.log('foo');` even if users answer is correct. This is so easy but I can't get why maybe I'm missing something or forget please help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Thinking...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span id="a">A</span> <span id="sign"></span> <span id="b">B</span> =
        <label for="result"></label><input type="number" id="result"> <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="checkResult()">press</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        let numberA = document.getElementById('a'),
            numberB = document.getElementById('b'),
            sign = document.getElementById('sign'),
            input = document.getElementById('result');

        function checkResult(a, b, sign, result) {

            if (sign === '-') {
                return a - b;
            } else if (sign === '+') {
                return a + b;
            }

            if (result === a-b || result === a+b) {
                console.log('hey');
            } else if (result !== a-b || result !== a+b) {
                console.log('foo');
            }

        }

        function getRandomSign() {
            let signs = ['-', '+'];
            return signs[Math.floor(Math.random()*signs.length)];
        }

        function getRandomNumber(a, b) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1)) + a;
        }

        let aRandom = numberA.innerHTML = getRandomNumber(1, 10);
        let bRandom = numberB.innerHTML = getRandomNumber(1, 10);
        let signRandom = sign.innerHTML = getRandomSign();

        console.log(checkResult(aRandom, bRandom, signRandom, input.value));

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"If `result` isn't equal to `a - b` __or__ it's not equal to `a + b`…"* — Well, it cannot be equal to both at the same time, so one of those conditions is guaranteed to be false.

Comment: The `console.log` call happens immediately, it doesn't wait for user input. So `input.value` in there is always the empty string. You need to somehow split your code into prompt (generate the numbers, show to the user) and answer (user pressed a button, answer is checked).

Comment: when you click the press button, it doesn't pass any argument, so no meaning here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var numberA = document.getElementById('a'),
    numberB = document.getElementById('b'),
    sign = document.getElementById('sign'),
    input = document.getElementById('result');
    
var aRandom = numberA.innerHTML = getRandomNumber(1, 10);
var bRandom = numberB.innerHTML = getRandomNumber(1, 10);
var signRandom = sign.innerHTML = getRandomSign();

function checkResult() {
    let temp;
    if (signRandom === '-') {
        temp = aRandom - bRandom;
    } else if (signRandom === '+') {
        temp = aRandom + bRandom;
    }
    if (temp === parseInt(input.value)) {
        console.log('hey');
    } else {
        console.log('foo');
    }

}

function getRandomSign() {
    let signs = ['-', '+'];
    return signs[Math.floor(Math.random()*signs.length)];
}

function getRandomNumber(a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1)) + a;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Thinking...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span id="a">A</span> <span id="sign"></span> <span id="b">B</span> =
        <label for="result"></label><input type="number" id="result"> <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="checkResult()">press</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```